# replace the authentication layer and user entity in sylius

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have created a symfony2 project and custom Authentication Provider (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) is used. my new task is to create an E-commerce application in sylius which should work alongside with my current symfony2 project. i want to make my current user table  in symfony2 project as user provider in sylius...is it possible to create such project..... since `fosUserBundle` and `fosOauthServer` bundel are installed in sylius how can i override these bundles with my custom authentication mechanism

My symfony2 project configurations are mentioned below

I tried the following in security.yml

```
 security:
     encoders:
         AppBundle\Entity\Users:
             algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Users

        api_key_user_provider:
            id: api_key_user_provider


    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            simple_preauth:
                authenticator: apikey_authenticator
            provider: api_key_user_provider    

        web:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~
            provider: our_db_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
```

this is my user class

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints=  {@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="users_user_name_unique", columns={"user_name"}),   @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="users_xmpp_password_unique", columns=  {"xmpp_password"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UsersRepository")
 */


class Users implements UserInterface, \Serializable {

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="parent_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $parentId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
private $lastName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_name", type="string", length=120, nullable=false)
 */
private $userName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="reg_type", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
 */
private $regType;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="oauth_uid", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $oauthUid;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $active;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="xmpp_password", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
 */
private $xmppPassword;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $createdAt = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $updatedAt = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $deletedAt;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="activation_code", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $activationCode;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_profile_pic", type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
 */
private $userProfilePic = 'uploads/defaults/user/profile_pic.jpg';

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_timeline_pic", type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
 */
private $userTimelinePic = 'uploads/defaults/user/timeline_pic.jpg';

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
 */
private $country;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
 */
private $state;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="hobbies", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
private $hobbies;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="interests", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
private $interests;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="about", type="string", length=500, nullable=false)
 */
private $about;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $gender;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dob", type="date", nullable=false)
 */
private $dob;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="quickblox_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $quickbloxId;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="privacy", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $privacy = '0';

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="school", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $school;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="college", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $college;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="work", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $work;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="relationship_status", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
 */
private $relationshipStatus;



public function getSalt() {
    // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
    // see section on salt below
    return null;
}



public function getRoles() {
    return array('ROLE_API');
}

public function eraseCredentials() {

}

/** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize() {
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
    ));
}

/** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
public function unserialize($serialized) {
    list (
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set parentId
 *
 * @param integer $parentId
 * @return Users
 */
public function setParentId($parentId) {
    $this->parentId = $parentId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get parentId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getParentId() {
    return $this->parentId;
}

/**
 * Set firstName
 *
 * @param string $firstName
 * @return Users
 */
public function setFirstName($firstName) {
    $this->firstName = $firstName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get firstName
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getFirstName() {
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * Set lastName
 *
 * @param string $lastName
 * @return Users
 */
public function setLastName($lastName) {
    $this->lastName = $lastName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lastName
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getLastName() {
    return $this->lastName;
}

/**
 * Set userName
 *
 * @param string $userName
 * @return Users
 */
public function setUserName($userName) {
    $this->userName = $userName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get userName
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getUserName() {
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set regType
 *
 * @param string $regType
 * @return Users
 */
public function setRegType($regType) {
    $this->regType = $regType;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get regType
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getRegType() {
    return $this->regType;
}

/**
 * Set oauthUid
 *
 * @param string $oauthUid
 * @return Users
 */
public function setOauthUid($oauthUid) {
    $this->oauthUid = $oauthUid;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get oauthUid
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getOauthUid() {
    return $this->oauthUid;
}

/**
 * Set active
 *
 * @param boolean $active
 * @return Users
 */
public function setActive($active) {
    $this->active = $active;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get active
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getActive() {
    return $this->active;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @return Users
 */
public function setEmail($email) {
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getEmail() {
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 * @return Users
 */
public function setPassword($password) {
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPassword() {
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set xmppPassword
 *
 * @param string $xmppPassword
 * @return Users
 */
public function setXmppPassword($xmppPassword) {
    $this->xmppPassword = $xmppPassword;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get xmppPassword
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getXmppPassword() {
    return $this->xmppPassword;
}

/**
 * Set createdAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $createdAt
 * @return Users
 */
public function setCreatedAt($createdAt) {
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createdAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getCreatedAt() {
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Set updatedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
 * @return Users
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt) {
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updatedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getUpdatedAt() {
    return $this->updatedAt;
}

/**
 * Set deletedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $deletedAt
 * @return Users
 */
public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt) {
    $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get deletedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDeletedAt() {
    return $this->deletedAt;
}

/**
 * Set activationCode
 *
 * @param string $activationCode
 * @return Users
 */
public function setActivationCode($activationCode) {
    $this->activationCode = $activationCode;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get activationCode
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getActivationCode() {
    return $this->activationCode;
}

/**
 * Set userProfilePic
 *
 * @param string $userProfilePic
 * @return Users
 */
public function setUserProfilePic($userProfilePic) {
    $this->userProfilePic = $userProfilePic;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get userProfilePic
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getUserProfilePic() {
    return $this->userProfilePic;
}

/**
 * Set userTimelinePic
 *
 * @param string $userTimelinePic
 * @return Users
 */
public function setUserTimelinePic($userTimelinePic) {
    $this->userTimelinePic = $userTimelinePic;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get userTimelinePic
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getUserTimelinePic() {
    return $this->userTimelinePic;
}

/**
 * Set country
 *
 * @param string $country
 * @return Users
 */
public function setCountry($country) {
    $this->country = $country;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get country
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCountry() {
    return $this->country;
}

/**
 * Set state
 *
 * @param string $state
 * @return Users
 */
public function setState($state) {
    $this->state = $state;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get state
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getState() {
    return $this->state;
}

/**
 * Set city
 *
 * @param string $city
 * @return Users
 */
public function setCity($city) {
    $this->city = $city;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get city
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCity() {
    return $this->city;
}

/**
 * Set hobbies
 *
 * @param string $hobbies
 * @return Users
 */
public function setHobbies($hobbies) {
    $this->hobbies = $hobbies;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get hobbies
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getHobbies() {
    return $this->hobbies;
}

/**
 * Set interests
 *
 * @param string $interests
 * @return Users
 */
public function setInterests($interests) {
    $this->interests = $interests;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get interests
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getInterests() {
    return $this->interests;
}

/**
 * Set about
 *
 * @param string $about
 * @return Users
 */
public function setAbout($about) {
    $this->about = $about;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get about
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAbout() {
    return $this->about;
}

/**
 * Set gender
 *
 * @param boolean $gender
 * @return Users
 */
public function setGender($gender) {
    $this->gender = $gender;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get gender
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getGender() {
    return $this->gender;
}

/**
 * Set dob
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dob
 * @return Users
 */
public function setDob($dob) {
    $this->dob = $dob;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dob
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDob() {
    return $this->dob;
}

/**
 * Set quickbloxId
 *
 * @param integer $quickbloxId
 * @return Users
 */
public function setQuickbloxId($quickbloxId) {
    $this->quickbloxId = $quickbloxId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get quickbloxId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getQuickbloxId() {
    return $this->quickbloxId;
}

/**
 * Set privacy
 *
 * @param boolean $privacy
 * @return Users
 */
public function setPrivacy($privacy) {
    $this->privacy = $privacy;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get privacy
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getPrivacy() {
    return $this->privacy;
}

/**
 * Set school
 *
 * @param string $school
 * @return Users
 */
public function setSchool($school) {
    $this->school = $school;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get school
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSchool() {
    return $this->school;
}

/**
 * Set college
 *
 * @param string $college
 * @return Users
 */
public function setCollege($college) {
    $this->college = $college;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get college
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCollege() {
    return $this->college;
}

/**
 * Set work
 *
 * @param string $work
 * @return Users
 */
public function setWork($work) {
    $this->work = $work;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get work
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getWork() {
    return $this->work;
}

/**
 * Set relationshipStatus
 *
 * @param string $relationshipStatus
 * @return Users
 */
public function setRelationshipStatus($relationshipStatus) {
    $this->relationshipStatus = $relationshipStatus;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get relationshipStatus
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getRelationshipStatus() {
    return $this->relationshipStatus;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to create such project... is this a proper method...

Comment: Latest Sylius has moved away from fos user

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer here https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/2931.

Comment: Please give more details

Comment: iam using sylius stantard edition.... how can i override sylius user provider  from my bundle...